# The prefix "wsdl" for attribute wsdl:arrayType associated with an element type attribute is not bound

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, soap

I am new to soap and I was asked to implement a soap connection with the optained wsdl file. While following this [guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Creating_a_Top-Down_Java_Web_Service_Skeleton_from_a_WSDL_Document), I ran into the following error:

> The prefix "wsdl" for attribute wsdl:arrayType associated with an element type attribute is not bound

The error occurred on line 14. The code snippet of the wsdl is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:ns2="urn:uSoapMwkInfo" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:ns3="urn:uSoapHistData" 
    xmlns:ns1="urn:uSoapType" name="INDAS_SOAP_SERVICEservice" 
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
            targetNamespace="urn:uSoapType">
      <complexType name="TActData">
        <sequence>
          <element name="cIdFound" type="boolean" />
          <element name="ValS" type="ns1:TDoubleArr" />
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
      <complexType name="TDoubleArr">
        <complexContent mixed="false">
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:float[]" />
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>
```

I could not find any solution yet and therefore I would like to know if anyone here could help me solving the problem?

**Update:**

With what Olivier told me, the error is gone, but I received tons of errors:

[ERROR] undefined simple or complex type 'soapenc:Array'

line 13, 21, 29, 37, 45, 62, 88

[ERROR] undefined attribute 'soapenc:arrayType'

line 15, 23 , 31, 39, 47, 64, 90

However, it should be declared, no?

```
      <xs:complexType name="THistDataArr">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
          <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <xs:sequence />
            <xs:attribute xmlns:n1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" n1:arrayType="ns3:THistData[]" ref="soapenc:arrayType" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
```

So anyone with more .wsdl knowledge may tell me what is wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to **wsdl** namespace is not defined.

But as http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ is the default namespace for your file you don't need a specific reference to it. So just remove it:

> <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" **arrayType**="xsd:float[]" />